# ignore a "floor" or "level" in the DOM structure

Tags: html, css, flexbox

For a responsive website, I have a structure like this :

```
<div class="menu_container">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>item menu 1</li>
        <li>item menu 1</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>item menu 2</li>
        <li>item menu 3</li>
        <li>item menu 4</li>
        <li>item menu 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

(exactly 2 *ul.menu*, but each has a not random number of *li.item*)
The "computer" version works five. But for the smarthphones, I need a structure like this :

```
<div class="menu_container">
        <li>item menu 1</li>
        <li>item menu 1</li>
        <li>item menu 2</li>
        <li>item menu 3</li>
        <li>item menu 4</li>
        <li>item menu 5</li>
</div>
```

Is there a way in CSS (no JS !) to "ignore" a "floor/level" in the DOM ? I need a flex behavior on the *item menus*, but the design is messed up by the fact that in the DOM, they are divided into 2.

What I wish to achieve : a vertical menu where all items take **the same available vertical-space**, but no more than 50px.

```
.menu_container{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
 }
.menu_container li{
    flex:1;
    max-height:50px;
}
```

Comment: consider reading the tag description before using them

Comment: display:contents might help you, unless https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents

Comment: @G-Cyr You are more than right ! Thanks a lot for your very quick answer !